# target a WooCommerce category's advanced custom field

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get the advanced custom field for a WooCommerce category. With the following code I get the woocommerce categories:

```html
$categories = get_terms('product_cat');
  var_dump($categories);
```

But why isn't any ACF info included? Is there another function which do gets the ACF info?

**UPDATE**

This is outside the loop. So I'm trying to get a custom field of a specific product category. I found this info: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

I can't get it to work.

**Answer**

To get the ACF with get_field(). I needed to use the cat_ID of the array I got with get_categories(). (Maybe it also works with get_terms())

I failed to grasp te second parameter in get_field()
I made it in the following way:

```html
$id = 'product_cat_' . $category->cat_ID;
echo get_field ('field_name', $id);
```

Comment: See [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). Meta is never returned. Please rephrase your question with what you are specifically trying to do.

Comment: I've got it to work. Thx helgatheviking for pointing me in te right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation of ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term) it appears you would get the custom term data as follows:

```
$category = get_term_by('slug', 'your-category', 'product_cat');
If( ! is_wp_error( $category ) && $custom_field = get_field('your_custom_field', $category ) ){
   echo $custom_field;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// get the current taxonomy term
$term = get_queried_object();

// vars
$image = get_field('image', $term);
$color = get_field('color', $term);
```

see documentation [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)

Comment: best answer on my case